# Excel 2007 - how to combine if and countif -functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using this order:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A100; "RED"); 1;2)
```

I have selected the column I want to place either 1 or 2 ( lets say column b). The result I have is 1 in cell B1 and nothing else. What I actually want is to check which A cell has the string "red" and place 1 in the equivalent B cell.

Comment: According to what you have written, you are not counting but just evaluating. That means you don't need COUNTIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to place in B1 the values 1/2 depending
if A1 is "RED"/or not.

Use the following formula for B1:

```
=IF(A1="RED",1,2)
```

(Your list-separator may be `;`.)

When the formula is working, click on B1 on the bottom-right border edge
and drag it down over the following B cells.

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: Mr.harrymc thanks for the advice. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:$A1,"RED")>0,1,2)
```

[image]

In your formula you should change the , to ;

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:$A1;"RED")>0;1;2)
```